# Why does RTC device have 254,0 instead of 10,135 as Major,Minor numbers?

Tags: linux, devices

Why isn't /dev/rtc the well known "c 10 135" device that it's on x86,
but a magic undocumented "c 254 0" device? 
Devices.txt lists this major number as LOCAL/EXPERIMENTAL USE.

I'm working on a buildroot custom board.

Answer (score 3):

The RTC subsystem went through a major redesign since at least 2006 and since then doesn't have a statically assigned major number, now.  This is a rather major trend in the Linux kernel for various device drivers (`device-mapper` for example also dynamically allocates its device-number region).  The reason behind this is that the vast amount of available drivers in the kernel makes it mere impossible to statically assign one device-number region for every supported device: there simply aren't enough (there are only 256 device major numbers), so you have to re-use existing major numbers.

**Edit:** You can read which device-number pair is allocated to the device from `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/dev`.

Comment: I have a static device table where I set the device drivers and the Maj,Min numbers. If I change the RTC number from 254 to -for example- 253 in this table then it doesn't work anymore. Or if I try to make a "mknod /dev/rtc" with other number. Then -as I see it- the RTC is fixed to this 254. Where is the dynamic allocation in it?

Comment: Of course it stops working if you arbitrarily change the major number.  The _kernel_ chose it to be what it is, not you by creating the device-node.  You can read the allocated major/minor number pair from `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/dev`.